# Link Error with Qt Win Migration Framework: unresolved symbol QWinWidget::staticMetaObject

Tags: qt, qt-mfc-migration

I'm trying to set up the Qt Win Migration framework to use Qt in an existing MFC based application. I want to use the framework as a library, so I ran `qmake` on the `qtwinmigrate/buildlib/buildlib.pro` file to create a Visual Studio vcxproj project file. I built the framework as a dll/lib and put the headers in a common include directory. In my MFC project, I added the Qt migration framework's lib as a dependency, included the headers where appropriate and added the code to test the framework. Everything compiles fine, but then I get a linker error:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QWinWidget::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QWinWidget@@2UQMetaObject@@B)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this forum post](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/25377-Problem-using-QWinWidget), a preprocessor definition must be added to the MFC project that's using the Qt Win Migration framework as a library. Simply add

`QT_QTWINMIGRATE_IMPORT`

to the project settings under `Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions`.

For a more in-depth explanation into why this is necessary, see [this blog post](http://linux.m2osw.com/unresolved-external-symbol-public-virtual-struct-qmetaobject-const-thiscall-myclassmetaobject).